# Why isn't this jQuery hover() working?

Tags: jquery, slidedown, slideup, onhover

I have 2 forms inside a custom HTML tag called `uptoppage`.

When the document loads, I slide up the element that holds the forms. Once someone hovers their mouse over the parent element again, I want it to slide down. Instead, nothing happens.

Here's my markup:

```
<uptoppage>controller....
  <uptpc>
    <form>.....</form>
    <form>......</form>
  </uptpc>
<uptoppage>
```

Here's the jQuery I'm using:

```
$("uptoppage").hover(function() {
  $('uptpc', this).slideDown();
}, function() {
  $('uptpc', this).slideUp();
});
```

Comment: Is there a good reason not to use valid HTML tags?

Comment: i have styles atteched to them all....

Comment: @YoungnateDaGreat - I edited your question to make it clearer and much easier to read. Many people will ignore questions that do not seem well-written, so it's worth your time to make your question as clear as possible. Even spelling and punctuation mistakes increase the amount of mental effort it takes to understand you. I'm not trying to lecture; I just want to help you ask better questions in the future so you're more likely to get help. You can click the link next to "edited" to see the changes I made, and edit it yourself to see how I did the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

### Watch for size changes

I don't see anything wrong with your use of `hover()` or your callback functions. I tinkered with your example; the main weird behavior I saw was if the child element is hidden and that causes the parent to becomes so small that it moves out from under the mouse.

In other words, jQuery is watching to see whether you're hovering over an element. If that element is growing and shrinking, it may change whether you're still over it, triggering the hover out, then the hover in, etc, without your mouse moving. So make sure that you have some other content in the parent element and/or it has some size given to it by CSS.

#### Check your markup

I'd also agree with the first comment: you shouldn't use custom elements if you can avoid it. I gave the parent element a border so that I could see how big it was, but the style didn't show up until I made it a div with an id instead a custom element type.

If at all possible, use ids and classes to identify standard elements instead of using custom ones. The more unusual your markup is, the more uncertain you'll be about problems - "Is this a problem with my JS, or is the browser choking on my custom HTML?"

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){ 
           $('form').hover(function(){
             $('form').slideUp();
             $(this).slideDown();
           });
        });
</script>
```